# Oracle 11g Current database sessions

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

```
set lines 100 pages 999
col ID format a15
select username
,      sid || ',' || serial# "ID"
,      status
,      last_call_et "Last Activity"
from   v$session
where  username is not null
order by status desc
,        last_call_et desc
/
```

Is the above query correct for displaying Session 
ID, Ownerʼs username and the session status (whether it is Waiting or On CPU) ? kindly advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `v$session_wait` view...

see: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/dynviews_3023.htm